# JQuery скрол вверх в Хроме

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, прокрутка

```
$("html").animate({"scrollTop":0},"slow");
```

Не работает скрол вверх в Хроме по событию `click()`. Только в хроме.

Comment: Может дело в событии click(), просто скролл в хроме работает?

Comment: да нет, там несколько действий привязано к этому событию, остальное работает...  может не нравится выбранный элемен html завтра буду эксперементировать

Answer (score 4):

```
$('html,body').animate({'scrollTop':0},'slow');
```

Comment: да! спасибо так работает.